# Watson Discovery -- Import a Model with a Object Storage connection

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-discovery

I have a SDU Model created and I need import this model in other collection. The documentation explain that is necessary add 1 document and then import the model.

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/discovery?topic=discovery-sdu#import

The problem is that my collection is connected with the object storage service with more than 1000 documents and not is possible add only one document and then import the model

I imported the model but SDU doesn't recognize my model. Is possible import a model with this type of connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After doing the initial crawl of Object Storage you should get the option to import the model.  If you are getting an error importing please post it here for further debugging.  (I am an IBM Watson employee)

Comment: I exported one model from a collection that is connected with one Object Storate. I created a new collection connected with the same OS and imported the model. The notices logs doesnt' show nothing and the status is allways is the same. '  "smart_document_understanding" : '{
    "enabled" : true,
    "total_annotated_pages" : 0,
    "total_pages" : 894,
    "total_documents" : 57,..'  I forced again the crawl and now the SDU is working but i need mark again the pages with the SDU tool. I can understand the mission of import/export tool if is necesary mark again the documents.